# If AO=AH. prove that angle A=60 degree.

Tags: geometry, triangles

$ABC$ is a triangle with the circumcenter $O$ and orthocenter $H$. If $AO=AH$, prove that  $m(\hat A)= 60^\circ$.

Also, if $H$ lies on the circumcircle of $BOC$, prove that $m(\hat A)= 60^\circ$.

Comment: This is homework. Don't expect us to do it for you. What have you tried ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$AH=2OM_1$ and $AH=AO=CO=R$ $ \Rightarrow OM_1=\frac12CO \Rightarrow \angle OCM_1 =30^{\circ}=\angle BOC$
Then in triangle $BOC:$ $$\angle BOC =180^{\circ}-2\cdot 30^{\circ}=120^{\circ} \Rightarrow \angle BAC =\frac12 \angle BOC=60^{\circ}$$